# Add mouse listener to JLabel in ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener, listcellrenderer

I have a ListCellRenderer that consist of two JLabels; one for text and one for an exit image (a little cross).

I want to add a mouselistener to that little cross, when clicked, the item is removed from the JList.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to add a listener to a rendering component (it's never part of the container hierarchy, so never will see any event). Instead add the listener to the list and check whether the event would be over the icon if the component had been added for rendering that line

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding MouseListener to your JList directly as follows,

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
   public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {               

             // Get the position of the click
              final int x = e.getX();
              final int y = e.getY();

              // Verify that the click occured on the selected cell
              final int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
          }
    }
});
```

Now depending on index above you can achieve what you want to do.

Comment: ehh .. what has the popupTrigger property to do with the question?